# That is the value of Ri, Ro, Voltage amplification

Tags: transistors

[image]Can someone explain what is happening in this circuit please?
I am asked to determine the amplification Au = uo/ui
[image]

Comment: A proper schematic would be easier to read. But what have you managed to work out so far?

Comment: What terminal is the input signal driving? What do you know about that terminal when the base voltage is held constant (approximately)? So what current does the input signal cause to flow in this terminal. Where does (almost all) of that current flow now? What is the load that current sees? So what is the output voltage? Are you sure you have identified the ui point correctly?

Comment: @Neil_UK this is the problem enunciation from the professor i have no other details. I may have misunderstood your answer, if so please say

Comment: Q:What terminal is the input signal driving?   A: the Emitor

Comment: Q:What do you know about that terminal when the base voltage is held constant (approximately)? A: This i don't know. If you can send me something to read please i would be very thankful

Comment: The professor ought to have given you something like a reading list : the texts on it ought to cover a simple common-base amplifier.